# What does "search localdomain" do in resolv.conf?

Tags: debian, dns, resolv.conf

When connecting to the Internet by default I get two lines in my /etc/resolv.conf file:

- search localdomain
- [nameserver {ipofmyrouter}](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/167766/resolv-conf-my-router-acts-as-a-nameserver-a-vulnerability-how-to-change-it)

I'd like to know what exactly "search localdomain" means there.
I see that it's probably related to DNS but I'm not sure how and couldn't find sufficient information on that. I also don't understand why it's getting removed [when I disconnect](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/386790/why-is-resolv-conf-emptied-every-time-i-dis-connect-from-the-internet-in-debian/386799) from the Internet - shouldn't it stay there?
I'm using Debian 9.1 with KDE.

Answer (score 5):

[`man resolv.conf`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/resolv.conf.5.html):

> **search**
>
> Search list for host-name lookup.
>
> The  search  list  is normally determined from the local domain name;
>   by default,  it  contains  only  the  local domain name.  This may be
>   changed by listing the desired domain search path following  the 
>   search  keyword  with spaces  or  tabs separating the names.  Resolver
>   queries having fewer than ndots dots (default is 1) in them will be 
>   attempted using each component of the search path in turn until a
>   match is found. (...)

`localdomain` here is your domain. When you make a DNS query with no dot (actually with fewer dots than the configuration value `ndots`), this domain is automatically added to your query. I.E. if you look up for `foo`, the actual DNS lookup will be for `foo.localdomain`.

Comment: The questioner also wanted to know why it was appearing and disappearing in that file.

Comment: @JdeBP Yes, in question 386790

Comment: Am I generating such DNS lookups when I enter search terms without a dot in Firefox ESR's address bar (for websearch and not for accessing local resources)? And do these DNS lookups in practice exit my LAN (wouldn't make sense as localdomain is local)?

Comment: @mYnDstrEAm 1. If your URL is `http://single_word/`, yes. Else, it really depends on the inner working of FF, it may try a lookup before a websearch. 2. Probably, AFAIK `localdomain` has nothing special. It depends of the DNS proxy embedded in your router and whether its domain has been set to `localdomain` too.